# Error while web-scraping using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am gathering housing data from zillow's website.So far I have gathered data from the first webpage.For my next step, I am trying to find links to the next button, which will navigate me to page 2, page 3, and so on. I used the Inspect feature of Chrome to locate the 'next button' button, which has the following structure

```
<a href=”/homes/recently_sold/house_type/47164_rid/0_singlestory/37.720288,-121.859322,37.601788,-121.918888_rect/12_zm/2_p/” class=”on” onclick=”SearchMain.changePage(2);return false;” id=”yui_3_18_1_1_1525048531062_27962">Next</a>
```

I then used  Beautiful Soup’s find_all method and filter on tag “a” and class “on”.I used the following code to extract all the links

> 

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)  
zillow_bellevue_1="https://www.zillow.com/homes/Bellevue-WA-98004_rb/"
driver.get(zillow_bellevue_1)   
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

next_button = soup.find_all("a", class_="on")  
print(next_button)
```

I am not getting any output.Any inputs on where I am going wrong?

Comment: Could you post a small reproducible example?

Comment: Do you want a shorter hmtl read out?

Comment: Just a small piece of code that runs from top to bottom and shows the issue you've described

Comment: [Selector Gadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) makes it very easy to write selectors for specific elements on a page. Also, if you're going to be following next button through many pages you might want to consider Scrapy instead of BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class for the `next` button appears to be `off` not `on`, as such you could scrape details of each property and advance through all the pages as follows. It uses the `requests` library to get the HTML which should be faster than using a chrome driver.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base_url = "https://www.zillow.com"
url = base_url + "/homes/Bellevue-WA-98004_rb/"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}    

while url:
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)   
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
    print('\n' + url)

    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="zsg-photo-card-caption"):
        print("  {}".format(list(div.stripped_strings)))

    next_button = soup.find("a", class_="off", href=True)  
    url = base_url + next_button['href'] if next_button else None
```

This continues requesting URLs until no next button is found. The output would be of the form:

```
https://www.zillow.com/homes/Bellevue-WA-98004_rb/
  ['New Construction', '$2,224,995+', '5 bds', '·', '4 ba', '·', '3,796+ sqft', 'The Castille Plan, Verano', 'D.R. Horton - Seattle']
  ['12 Central Square', '2', '$2,550+', '10290 NE 12th St, Bellevue, WA']
  ['Apartment For Rent', '$1,800/mo', '1 bd', '·', '1 ba', '·', '812 sqft', '10423 NE 32nd Pl APT E105, Bellevue, WA']
  ['House For Sale', '$1,898,000', '5 bds', '·', '4 ba', '·', '4,030 sqft', '3230 108th Ave SE, Bellevue, WA', 'Quorum Real Estate/Madison Inc']
  ['New Construction', '-- bds', '·', '-- ba', '·', '-- sqft', 'Coming Soon Plan, Northtowne', 'D.R. Horton - Seattle']
  ['The Meyden', '0', '$1,661+', '1', '$2,052+', '2', '$3,240+', '10333 Main St, Bellevue, WA']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier if you are using soup.findAll

my solution goes this way:

```
zillow_url = URL
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(zillow_url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

prices = ["$" + re.sub(r'(\s\d)|(\W)|([a-z]+)', "", div.text.split("/")[0], ) for div in
          soup.find_all('div', class_='list-card-price')]
# print(prices)
addresses = [div.text for div in
             soup.findAll('address', class_='list-card-addr')]

urls = [x.get('href')  if 'http' in x.get('href') else 'https://www.zillow.com' + x.get('href') for x in soup.find_all("a", class_="list-card-link list-card-link-top-margin list-card-img")]
```